# BankAccount java program not showing output

Tags: java

I made this program and i don`t understand why is not showing anything , if someone can give me an advice or any hint about it . I would really appreciate it.

**First part of the text** https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOHTV.jpg

**Second part** https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCa2b.jpg

```
import java.util.Calendar;

abstract class BankAccount{
    private double balance=0;
    private String owner;
    private int id;
    private int idCurrentAccount=1;

    public BankAccount(String owner,double balance){
        this.owner=owner;
        this.id=idCurrentAccount++;
        this.balance=balance;    
    }

    public void deposit(double sum){
        this.balance=this.balance+sum;
        System.out.println("You just added "+sum+" in your account.You have know: "+balance);
    }

    public void withdraw(double sum){
        if(sum>balance) 
            System.out.println("Sorry.Not enough money to withdraw!");
        else{
            System.out.println("You just withdrawed "+sum+" from "+balance+".Have a nice day!");
            balance=balance-sum;
        }
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public String getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return owner+balance+id+idCurrentAccount;
    }

    public abstract void endOfMonth();
}

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{
    private double interestRate;

    public SavingsAccount(String owner,double balance,double interestRate){
        super(owner,balance);     
        this.interestRate=interestRate;
    }

    public void applyInterest(){
        deposit(getBalance()*interestRate);   
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString()+interestRate;
    }

    @Override
    public void endOfMonth(){
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
        int nextDayMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        if(currentMonth!=nextDayMonth){
            applyInterest();    
        } 
    }
}

class CurrentAccount extends BankAccount{
    private int transactionNo=0;
    final int FREE_TRANSACTIONS=5;
    double TRANSACTION_COST;

    public CurrentAccount(String owner, double balance, int transNr, double transCost){
        super(owner,balance);
        this.transactionNo=transNr;
        this.TRANSACTION_COST=transCost;
    }

    public void dischargeExpenses() {
        if(transactionNo>FREE_TRANSACTIONS)
            withdraw(getBalance()-TRANSACTION_COST);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString()+transactionNo+TRANSACTION_COST; 
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(double sum){
        super.deposit(sum);
        transactionNo++;
    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(double sum){
        super.withdraw(sum);
        transactionNo++;
    }

    @Override
    public void endOfMonth(){
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
        int nextDayMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        if(currentMonth!=nextDayMonth){
            dischargeExpenses();
            transactionNo=0;
        }   
    }
}

public class Llab12{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SavingsAccount a = new SavingsAccount("Dan",1000,100);
        SavingsAccount b = new SavingsAccount("Alex",10000,1000);
        CurrentAccount c = new CurrentAccount("Dan",200000,10,100);
        CurrentAccount d = new CurrentAccount("Alex",200000,33,100);
        a.toString(); //Not showing output
        b.toString(); //Not showing output
        c.toString(); //Not showing output
        d.toString(); //Not showing output
        c.deposit(300);
        d.deposit(900);
        c.getBalance(); //Not showing output
        d.getBalance(); //Not showing output
        c.deposit(3007);
        d.withdraw(9);
        c.getBalance(); //Not showing output
        d.getBalance(); //Not showing output
        c.endOfMonth(); //Not showing output
        d.endOfMonth(); //Not showing output
        c.toString(); //Not showing output
        d.toString(); //Not showing output      
    }       
}
```

Comment: You need to do `System.out.println(METHOD CALL)` anytime you want an output.

Comment: When I run your code it shows `You just added 300.0 in your account.You have know: 200300.0  
You just added 900.0 in your account.You have know: 200900.0  
You just added 3007.0 in your account.You have know: 203307.0  
You just withdrawed 9.0 from 200900.0.  Have a nice day!`

Comment: Did you run the right code?

Comment: Yes , but it is not showing me : The id , owner or idCurrentAccount and i don t know why

Comment: As @EliSadoff wrote, you have to call `System.out.println` on anything you need to print. So instead of `a.toString()` use `System.out.println(a.toString())`. Use this for any line that you want to print.

Comment: Ty you all for your help . Have a nice day .

Comment: Sorry i did not realize .

Comment: No problem, thanks for reverting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i ran your program, i got the following:

```
You just added 300.0 in your account.You have know: 200300.0
You just added 900.0 in your account.You have know: 200900.0
You just added 3007.0 in your account.You have know: 203307.0
You just withdrawed 9.0 from 200900.0.Have a nice day!
```

As others suggested in the comment section, you need to print the output using `System.out.println()`. So, i changed your one line of code as follows:

```
System.out.println(a.toString()); // instead of a.toString()
```

It outputs:

```
Dan 1000.0 1 2100.0
```

I have modified your `toString()` method of `abstract class BankAccount` as follows: [**just added space between the values**]

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return owner + " " + balance + " " + id + " " + idCurrentAccount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you expected some text printed on the command line while the appliction executes.
Printing the information is typically done by System.out.println or for e.g. errors System.err.println. Here is an example:

```
System.out.println("This is a test");
```

In your code you have a lot of statements without effect, i.e. the call `a.toString();` This one returns a string, but then you are doing nothing with it. If you would like to have `a` printed to the console, please change the implementation to

```
System.out.println(a);
```

(`toString()` can be omitted in this case.)